# submit form if two functions return true on click

Tags: javascript

I am calling 2 js functions onclick event. I want to submit the form only if both the functions return true. Here if first function returns true then form is getting submitted.

```
    <apex:commandButton value="Approve" onclick="return validateCAMDiv1('ApproveId'); return fraudCheck();" action="{!approve}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that validateCAMDiv1 and fraudCheck are having return statements.

```
<apex:commandButton value="Approve" onclick="validateCAMDiv1('ApproveId') && fraudCheck();" action="{!approve}" />
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

```
return validateCAMDiv1('ApproveId') && fraudCheck();
```